# Only selected radio label visible when readonly

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an input form for gender.
When readonly is false, there are radiobuttons to select between: 
[image: Readonly: False]
But when readonly is true it is only showing the real value, but I want the label of the selected radiobutton to be shown instead. How should I do this (in a nice way)?
[image: Readonly: True]
It should be "männlich", not 'M'.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="form-group {{selectedProfile.gender ? '' : 'has-error'}}">
    <label for="gender" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Geschlecht</label>
    <div id="gender" class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" ng-model="selectedProfile.gender" class="form-control"
               ng-if="readonly" ng-disabled="readonly"/>
        <label ng-if="!readonly">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedProfile.gender" value="M">
            männlich
        </label>
        <label ng-if="!readonly">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedProfile.gender" value="F">
            weiblich
        </label>
        <label ng-if="!readonly">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedProfile.gender" value="U">
            keine Angabe
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not making the value identical to label?

Comment: @BaselIssmail because the label might be later replaced with language specific translations

Comment: If you provide the function which changes the readonly variable would be helpful to answer.

Comment: @BaselIssmail `readonly = !readonly`, this code is executed when I click an edit/finish button, but I don't really understand how this is important

Comment: Why not binding other variable than selectedProfile.gender to your input like selectedProfile.getnderLabel, and when executing your code put a condition, when selectedProfile.gende is m, let selectedProfile.getnderLabel = männlich, and in this case you can handle other languages too.

Comment: @BaselIssmail I get ur idea, but I don't know how to implement this easily and replacing the old hardcoded label values with it too since I don't want to have redundancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Basel Issmail comment, you can create an array containing the gender label and gender values. use `ng-repeat` to display the radio button and in `ng-change` change the label.

```
 <label ng-if="!readonly" ng-repeat="gender in genderList">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedProfile.gender" value="{{gender.value}}" 
          ng-change="selectedProfile.genderLabel = gender.label">
        {{gender.label}}
  </label>
```

[JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/jxgnLm32/9/)

Comment: I did it without the selectedProfile.genderLabel, but your code was enough for me to understand how to solve this easily, thanks